# Issue in pagenumbering with arabic ldf (babel)

Tags: pdftex, numbering, babel, arabic

I have this example, with `arabic` as second language `\pagenumbering{roman}` do not change page numbering form to roman

**Remark**

If we remove chapter headings changing of page numbering becomes possible.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[arabic,french]{babel}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
 %\renewcommand{\thepage}{foo} 

\chapter{First chap} % problem does not appear if we remove chapter headings
\section{First sec}

\newpage
text 
\newpage
text 

\end{document}
```

Comment: arabic redefines tons of things and is unmaintained. Why do you want to use it instead of using xelatex or lualatex?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This is a request from a friend who wrote a graduation note using french as main language and he need to add some lines in arabic, the report use babel with pdflatex engine.

Comment: If he wants only a few lines he shouldn't use Arabic but switch only the font and direction locally

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I think it is easier to use just `\selectlanguage{arabic}` instead of including Arabic with `\fontencoding`, `\beginR` and other commands for font switching.

Comment: Only if you ignore all the problems (like the one in your question) you will have to solve because Arabic redefines almost everything.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Isn't the change supposed to take place in the Arabic  context only?

Comment: sorry it doesn't matter "what it is supposed to do", you can see from your question that it affects other things. Check arabicore.sty loaded by the language to see what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within file `arabicore.sty` we can find redefinition of `\ps@plain`, `\ps@myheadings` and `\ps@headings` which includes redefinition of `\thepage` command

```
\let\SAV@ps@plain\ps@plain
\let\SAV@ps@myheadings\ps@myheadings
\let\SAV@ps@headings\ps@headings
%
\def\ps@plain{\ps@empty%
\gdef\thepage{\protect\if@rlmain\protect\I{\number\c@page}%
\protect\else\protect\textLR{\number\c@page}%
\protect\fi}%
\SAV@ps@plain}
%
\def\ps@myheadings{\ps@empty%
\gdef\thepage{%
\protect\if@rlmain\protect\I{\number\c@page}%
\protect\else\protect\textLR{\number\c@page}%
\protect\fi}%
\SAV@ps@myheadings}
%
\def\ps@headings{\ps@empty%
\gdef\thepage{%
\protect\if@rlmain\protect\I{\number\c@page}%
\protect\else\protect\textLR{\number\c@page}%
\protect\fi}%
\SAV@ps@headings}
```

We need to restore the initial definitions of macros with

```
\let\ps@plain\SAV@ps@plain
\let\ps@myheadings\SAV@ps@myheadings
\let\ps@headings\SAV@ps@headings
```

And the example become

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic,french]{babel}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\SAV@ps@plain
\let\ps@myheadings\SAV@ps@myheadings
\let\ps@headings\SAV@ps@headings
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thepage}{foo}
%\pagenumbering{roman}

\chapter{First chap}
\section{First sec}

\newpage
text 
\newpage
text 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The support for Arabic in `pdftex` is a separate package (`arabi`). See https://ctan.org/pkg/arabi. I think it was meant mainly for mostly Arabic documents, so I wouldn't be surprised if there are changes in the code for the layout. However, for short texts (a few words), it's easy to define a simple macro:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[LAE,T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[spanish, bidi=default]{babel}

\newcommand\usearabic[1]{{\fontencoding{LAE}\selectfont\beginR#1\endR}}

\begin{document}

Text \usearabic{اثنين ثلاثة} text \usearabic{ثلاثة} text.

\end{document}
```