# Appendix referencing is not working when using arabic with babel

Tags: hyperref, babel, appendices, appendix

I am using arabic and french in a `report` document using babel, the arabic is used for the abstract and it's not used in the appendix (the appendix is 100% in french).

When using only french in babel and writing `\ref{appendix:some_appendix}` the reference is replaced with the appendix letter (like A, B, C, etc) which is what I would like to have.

When I add arabic to babel `\usepackage[arabic,french]{babel}`, the reference to the appendix is changed to a number like 2.4.1 even though I don't have any arabic in my appendices.

It seems like it's a bug with babel and hyperref package.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please always provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). Without seeing some code, it's impossible to know what you're doing and test it.

Comment: The following links may help: https://latex3.github.io/babel/guides/locale-arabic.html#pdftex , https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/601538/5735 .